# Security rule to only allow write for users with verified emails

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have very simple write security rule that should only allow users with verified email to write data,

```
"someNode": {
  ".write": "auth.token.emailVerified === true"
}
```

For some reason I am still getting permission denied in simulator with specific users token and in my app with same user. I double checked user object in client and it indeed has `emailVerified === true` hence I am not sure to why this is not working.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the simulator failing? This screenshot should have the path, the rules, the user auth that you specified in the simulator, the failure and the data you're writing.

Comment: test at the client side will be easier

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added, I was only able to use Anonymous auth in simulator, but uid token passed to it is from a test user authenticated via `Email/Password`, same user tested from an actual client (not simulator) receives error of  `permission denied` for same rules

Comment: The simulator does not read the actual token of the user. Only the payload that you enter in the simulator is available when simulating the security rules. For anonymous accounts that means that you only get `provider` and `uid`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen indeed adding that payload in manually in simulator worked, however still experiencing issue in client, where I receive `FIREBASE WARNING: set at /queue/create/tasks/-Kdvoc0u3OWz3_LTDku1 failed: permission_denied` for user who has `emailVerified: true` where `task` refers to `someNode` in my question, changing the rule to `auth !== null` works fine

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen found a solution and posted answer, but that was a lucky find in some forum. If you look at my answer, could you tell me if there is reference in docs I could view that shows that it is `email_verified` that needs to be used? I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: @Ilja  One more thing. Firebase examples use != and == instead of strict equality. It should be worth knowing the impact of using either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out `auth.token.emailVerified` should be `auth.token.email_verified` its a bit inconsistent with how such data is presented on client side.

Comment: Darn. I was considering that immediately when I saw your question, but thought I'd just misremembered the syntax. I should've checked. :-/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I wasn't able to find any reference to this in the docs :/ and it is actually presented as `emailVerified` in user object we get from javascript SDK on client, hence is a bit misleading.

Comment: It *is* documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken