# Firebase email verification flow broken?

Tags: authentication, firebase

Firebase email/password account creation and email verification seems broken. It appears your are automatically logged in after creating a new account (on android at least) and it seems you have to login in order to call `user.SendEmailVerification()`. After the user clicks the link in the email a web page says

> You can now log in to your account

That's neat - but the user is *already* logged in. Is it possible to create a new email/password account without automatically logging in and to request email verification without first logging into the unverified account?

It's possible to use a cloud function to create the account currently, solving the first problem - but it does not seem possible to request email verification that way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this reads like a feature request or bug report.  Please send Firebase feature requests and bug reports here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Been reported doug. Please answer the question. Or confirm it's a bug.

Comment: are you using javascript(web), swift(ios), objective-c(ios), or java(android)?

Comment: android java sdk, C++ sdk, java and javascript admin sdks.

Answer (score 0):

A user's email address does not have to be verified for that user to sign in. In fact, all they need to know is the credentials: so email address + password for email/password authentication, whatever credentials the social provider (Facebook, Twitter, Github, Google) requires, or event just the phone number on which to receive a verification text message.

If you want to limit what a user without a verified email address can do, you should check in the token of that user whether they have a verified email address. For example, to [limit access to the database to users with a verified email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470120/security-rule-to-only-allow-write-for-users-with-verified-emails):

```
".read": "auth.token.email_verified === true"
```

For Cloud Storage the syntax is slightly different, but the logic is the same. If you have other back-end service that you want to integrate with Firebase Authentication, you can [decode the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) and check if `email_verified` is true.

If there is a bug, it is in the message of the email that seems to hint that you can now log in - as if you couldn't log in before. The correct message should say that the user *may* have to reauthenticate in order for the app to know that they've verified their email address (the token in the app doesn't immediately pick that fact up, since it's a so-called out-of-bounds verification).

Comment: Hmm, seems like that is inviting identity fraud.  But, it seems other mainstream apps (twitter, snapchat, and others) are doing the same so I guess so be it.  Apparently, the answer to people using your identity by making an account using your email, is to request a forgotten password and retake control. Wow. The fact that the incorrect email is hardcoded by Firebase is also a serious problem that can't be corrected.